# Read XML node attributes without using node name in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-attribute

I have XML stored into database with the different tag names but the same attribute names:

```
<book Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="C#" CategoryID="44" />
<sport Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="Cricket" CategoryID="46" />
```

These are just two examples but the tag name can be anything. I want to read "PropertyName" attribute from all node.

Is it possible? If yes then please anyone guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = '<book Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="C#" CategoryID="44" />
<sport Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="Cricket" CategoryID="46" />'

select T.c.value('@PropertyName', 'varchar(100)')
from @xml.nodes('/*') T(c)
```

If you expect that there can be elements without PropertyName attribute, you can use:

```
select T.c.value('@PropertyName', 'varchar(100)')
from @xml.nodes('/*[@PropertyName]') T(c)
```

If you also expect that elements can be nested, you can use:

```
select T.c.value('@PropertyName', 'varchar(100)')
from @xml.nodes('//*[@PropertyName]') T(c)
```

Comment: @i-one: look at this query `DECLARE @x XML; SET @x=N'<book Category="Hobbies And Interests" CategoryID="44"><chapter PropertyName="111" /></book><sport Category="Hobbies And Interests" CategoryID="46" />'; SELECT T.c.value('@PropertyName', 'VARCHAR(100)') FROM @x.nodes('/*') T(c);` that returns only NULLs thought there is a `PropertyName` attribute.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, you right. But in the original data there are no nested elements, and that was the assumption. If necessary it can be generalized by changing `.nodes('/*')` to `.nodes('//*[@PropertyName]')`. In any case I have no influence on accept marks.

Comment: I agree that the test data provided hasn't nested elements. My point is that OP "want[s] to read "PropertyName" attribute from *all* node[s].".