# How to get XML value from a column in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table `tblApplications` with some columns... one of the columns is called `Content` and has XML values like in the following Image:

[image]

when i clicked on the value of content in the above image it displays like following in new tab

[image]

I want to get the value using id from the xml value of `dataitem` that is under the `datagroupItem` of `datagroup` as selected in following image, using query from the `tblApplications`

How to get the value from the content using id?? E.g. I want to get the value of id of dataitem = 'ForeNames'

How to get it using query????

Comment: You need to show us the **complete** XML stored in that column - paste it as text into your question - don't post a picture, please!

Comment: God, I hope that's not a real person :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT  a.application_id,
    x.y.query('.') AS DataItemNode,
    x.y.value('(@type)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS TypeAttr,
    x.y.value('(@value)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS ValueAttr
FROM    dbo.tblApplications a
CROSS APPLY a.Content.nodes('/XmlDataPairDocument/dataitem/datagroup/datagroupitem/dataitem[@id="forenames"]') x(y)
```

or

```
DECLARE @id NVARCHAR(50);
SET @id='forenames';

SELECT  a.application_id,
    x.y.query('.') AS DataItemNode,
    x.y.value('(@type)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS TypeAttr,
    x.y.value('(@value)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS ValueAttr
FROM    dbo.tblApplications a
CROSS APPLY a.Content.nodes('/XmlDataPairDocument/dataitem/datagroup/datagroupitem/dataitem[@id = sql:variable("@id")]') x(y)
```

Another similar questions-answers: [here #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891747/how-do-you-get-a-node-that-contains-a-child-node-with-a-given-attribute-value-in/17896976#17896976), [here #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857468/read-xml-node-attributes-without-using-node-name-in-sql-server-query/17858329#17858329)